# Google Maps, is it possible to use a Material Icon as a map marker?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-markers

Is it possible to use the Material Icons in Flutter as Markers in a Flutter app with the GoogleMap widget?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's not too late: Yes, it is possible - but requires some steps: You draw an icon (which is basically a character within an icon font) on a Canvas, write the Canvas's content to PNG data and then instantiate a Marker with it. I actually wrote an [article](https://link.medium.com/jnNuh2lMl3) on how to do it.